# Haxe -> Javascript target for CommonJs (NodeJs) style output

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, haxe, commonjs

Haxe's JavaScript exports everything in a Haxe compilation into a single output file. This is great for building applications. For a general purpose library, however, it would be nice if it output a `*.js` file per `*.hx` file within my compiled sources.

The intent of this is so that I can create a NodeJs module where the consumer of the library only needs to `require()` the particular files that they would like to use. Is this currently possible using the Haxe compiler on its own, or via an external tool?

Comment: Does http://lib.haxe.org/p/modular-js look helpful? Looks like CommonJs module support is planned

Answer (score 1):

There is the hxgenjs library that can generate one js file per haxe class/enum.

https://github.com/kevinresol/hxgenjs

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 different questions here

1. How to output Haxe module as a NodeJS module?
2. How to build each JS file into separated output file?

As for #1 there is [@:expose](https://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-expose.html) directive and it should help.

As for #2 you can use [--each and --next](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-hxml.html) in your build *.hxml file. This way you can specify several targets at once(and they will be built at once too). Unfortunately there is no way to use the mask so you will have to list all your entry points(modules' roots) manually.